# Specifically, what makes some words harder to spell, pronounce, and remember?

Tags: pronunciation, linguistics, spelling-pronunciations

Edit: I apologize if my question lacks research effort, and is neither clear nor useful. Perhaps if you could tell me why this is in conjunction with your downvote, the quality of my post might be able to improve.

I have never been able to nail down a solid answer, or set of answers for this. What specifically makes some words more difficult to spell and pronounce than others? What makes some less memorable than others?

Examples:

Easy Words:

- Kepler
- Vanguard
- Titan

More Difficult Words:

- Fobos
- Helios
- kudrun
- lambaste

More Difficult:

- Luhman
- Gennai
- Leonis
- philtre

Far More Difficult:

- Poudreuse
- kweilin
- lepaute

Comment: They function under a different set of rules?

Comment: I am looking for a more in depth answer than that. How can it be described, what interaction do the consonants and syllables have that make it difficult? As an example, Syllabic Ambiguities make some words more difficult to pronounce.

Comment: Some words are more common and therefore more familiar than others.  These words are easier to spell.  This is obviously not the only factor, but I expect it accounts for the difference between vanguard and leonis, for example.

Comment: There's no specific answer. There's the general answer that English has a messed up history of orthography. So there are spelling rules, but these have exceptions, and those exceptions have exceptions (and so on) and then some words are just spelled weird for very specific reasons. And there are just too many words to spell that out specifically here.

Comment: So there is no describable way or study in modern linguistics that can say what components of a word can make it difficult to say? I would have thought that to be a known area, since a simple google search leads you to a few webpages that provide referenced, though incomplete, information on what components certain words have that make them difficult to pronounce.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spelling a word depends on hearing it, and in your list, with the exception of 'vanguard', the "simpler" words employ largely conventional phonetic orthography. Consequently, even upon hearing them for the first time, someone can intuit their spelling using knowledge of phonetic orthographic conventions; the more "difficult" words, OTOH, have uncommon or unintuitive orthography, so the listener is not able to leverage their knowledge of existing conventions.